# What is Meaning of 3.3882e+004 -1.9521e+001i in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, numbers, number-formatting, scientific-notation, complex-numbers

What does this number "3.3882e+004 -1.9521e+001i" means in Matlab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a complex number with 3.3882e+004 real part and -1.9521e+001 imaginary part.

More about complex numbers: [Complex number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number)

Comment: and 3.3882e+004 is another way to write 33,882 (the other number is -19.521i)

Comment: @Thilo: Yes, thank you! *Scientific notation* so to say (more on it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation )

Comment: @Thilo:is there any way to get out such numbers and see more understandable ones?

Comment: Yes, there is! See: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/format.html But scientific notation is no so bad. You just need to get used to it.